# Distill failed for unknown reasons

Tags: react-native

When I run the build I am getting this error: Distill failed for unknown reasons in Xcode. I don't why image.xcassets showing this error

Version
Xcode(11)
macos(10.15)

Comment: Solved. By Upgrading  latest mac OS and Xcode

Comment: i have xcode 11.3.1 you mean we shoul upgrade to beta ?